# Simple nested form, but doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm trying to build a simple nested form, checking a lot of resources online, but can't find what is it that I'm missing!
I have the following:

```
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :configoptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :configoptions
end

class Configoption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :configuration
  has_many :items
end
```

Now, I'm trying to make a simple form when you select a configuration so it would show the 
configoptions belonging to it, but nothing works!

This is the view without any html

```
  <%= form_for :config do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:name)%>
    <% f.fields_for @options do |option|%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

In the controller I have:

```
  def show
    @config = Configuration.find(params[:id])
    @options = @config.configoptions
  end
```

But i end up getting the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class
```

Does anyone have advice for me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, Ryan Bates (RailsCasts) has created a gem to handle much of this. I'm using it now and it works great!

See https://github.com/reu/simple_nested_form for the details.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to specify a model_name if you are using a collection (like an array).

```
  <%= form_for :config do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:name)%>
    <%= f.fields_for :configoptions, @options do |option|%>
      <%= option.text_field(:some_attribute) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

In fields_for I am passing two arguments, `:configoptions` as the model name and `@options` as the collection to use.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html has a ton of great nested attribute examples if you scroll down just above half way.

Alternatively (and my personal preferred method) is to loop through the collection and call `fields_for` for each object.

```
  <%= form_for :config do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:name)%>
    <% @options.each do |configoption| %>
      <%= f.fields_for configoption do |option|%>
        <%= option.text_field(:some_attribute) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. When I try the second method you suggested, I actually get what I need, as all the different options are listed. However on the first one, for some reason it doesn't. In my options, some will be dropdowns, which the user will be able to choose from. Is there a way you could suggest a method once i press the submit button, to create a new configuration with the options chosen in the form? What do you think? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey `accepts_nested_attributes` should handle taking care of creating the configuration with the chosen options.  In your controller you just need to have `@conf = Configuration.build(params[:config]); @conf.save` to build the configuration and the nested config options objects.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :configoptions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :configoptions, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You used:

```
<% f.fields_for @options do |option|%>
```

try using

```
<%= f.fields_for @options do |option|%>
```

I had the same problem, it was solved by this trivial idea.

Comment: lack of output won't result in rails saying "undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class"